# How to get Tax inclusive price in Code Magento 1.9

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Losing sleep over this one! Magento is set to display tax exclusive prices.

However - under some circumstances , I want to display the price inclusive of Tax. Tax is set up properly because if I switch it globally to inclusive it will display inclusive prices.

The following line of Code always gives me the tax exclusive price. I am baffled as to how to get the tax inclusive price. Is there a new way of calculating this since 1.3?

```
$_finalPriceInclTax = $this->helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice(), true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the price inclusive of tax.

```
$_priceIncludingTax = Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getPrice(), true, null, null, null, null, false);
```

Comment: Nope. exactly the same - shows tax exclusive. I am using Magento 1.9.2 don't know if that makes a difference.